# Snapping doesn't work - MapInfo Pro 17 (64 bit)

Tags: editing, mapinfo, snapping, tab

I've experienced a strange behaviour during drawing in MapInfo. Snap function doesn't work. Pressing the S key has no effect. I can't turn off snap. When I start drawing in snap mode, the program freezes. Any ideas what the reason is?

Comment: sounds like a bug, you should report it to the devs. did you make sure the layer you want to digitize on is editable?

Comment: yes, the layer is editable :) SNAP should be displayed on the bottom bar when the snap function is active and when it's not active, it's gone, but my program doesn't respond to pressing the S. SNAP key is still active and I can't turn it off. Next the program freezes.

Answer (score 1):

Some years back I saw a client with some seriously bad performance with snap enabled. It turned out their data was on a network drive, they had a poor network connection and finally, they have 50-70 layers all selectable.

A few hints:

- try to only make one layer selectable, the one you want to snap to. You can right-click the layer and use *Make all other layers not selectable*. Or at least limit the number of selectable layers if you have a lot of layers.
- try to use the *Snap* options from the *Nodes* dropdown on the *SPATIAL* tab

[image]